# Wordpress not displaying taxonomies

Tags: wordpress

I'm in the process of making a Twenty Ten theme child theme and I have a page that is not displaying the posts of some custom taxonomies that I've set up on my functions.php page. However I can see the the individual posts, I just can't get them to preview on a page.

on the preview page I'm using the following to display the excerpt posts

```
<?php if ( is_page('photo-gallery') ) {  query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'cat' => '13,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); } ?>
```

and on the functions.php page I have:

```
 add_action('init', 'gallery_register');

function gallery_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Photo Gallery', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Gallery Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'gallery item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Gallery Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Gallery Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Gallery Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Gallery Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Gallery'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','comments','revisions','excerpt','page-attributes')
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'gallery' , $args );
}

register_taxonomy("photo_categories", array("gallery"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Photos Categories", "singular_label" => "Photo", "rewrite" => true));
```

It's probably quite simple but I can't see what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well if anyone else is struggling with custom post types, I found the solution by reading [this brilliant article at Monday By Noon](http://mondaybynoon.com/2011/05/20/revisiting-custom-post-types-taxonomies-permalinks-slugs/).